# Package doesnt run when moved to production

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am not sure this should be in this category or not but here is my issue.

I have an SSIS package that I am trying to move to our production server. It works fine on the QA server but now that I have moved it to production I am getting errors:

```
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Native Client" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Login timeout expired".
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Native Client" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that 
under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.".
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Native Client" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ".
End Error
Error: 2016-02-08 14:01:51.24
 Code: 0xC020801C
 Source: Data Flow Task OLE DB Destination [39652]
 Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "MYSERVER.MYDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted before this with more 
information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
```

These errors are occurring when I try to run the package from the stored procedure I created to run the package when initiated through Access.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_import] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @ServerName VARCHAR(200) 
SET @ServerName = 'MYSERVER' 
SET @SQLQuery = 'DTExec /F ^"\\MYSERVER\Import\Package.dtsx^" '
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQLQuery
END
```

I should mention that the package, source file and database are all located on the same machine.

Thanks

Comment: Enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP Connections in your production: https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm

Comment: Thanks but named pipes is already enabled

Comment: I'm confused on all the moving parts to your problem. We have SSIS, SQL Server, Access and a stored procedure and a UNC path. Could you perhaps describe the architecture behind the problem you are attempting to solve and the mechanics of solving it

Answer (score -1):

your problem is on relation with autorisation access, change your connection to the server from windows to authentification by sql server on the connection manager and give a account that have the autorisations.